# PHP use string as operator

Tags: php, expression, operator-keyword, evaluate

Say I have a string, `$char. $char == "*".`

I also have two variables, $a and $b, which equal "4" and "5" respectively.

How do I get the result of `$a $char $b, ie 4 * 5 ?`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `eval()` as suggested by @konforce, however the safest route would be something like:

```
$left = (int)$a;
$right = (int)$b;
$result = 0;
switch($char){

  case "*":
    $result = $left * $right;
    break;

 case "+";
   $result = $left + $right;
   break;
// etc

}
```

Comment: that's the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 10):

safest method is a switch construct:

```
function my_operator($a, $b, $char) {
    switch($char) {
        case '=': return $a = $b;
        case '*': return $a * $b;
        case '+': return $a + $b;
        etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: yep...people answer too fast!

Comment: if the operator is `=` your code will produce `sum` of operands. Should not there be a `break`?

Comment: The '=' wouldn't do anything in this case, unless $a was passed in as a reference. The assignment would be lost as soon as the function returns, otherwise. It's just an example.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh No need for `break` when there's `return`

Answer (score 6):

The easiest but most dangerous method is to use `eval`.

```
$c = eval("return $a $char $b;");
```

Comment: I'd rather not use eval as the values come from user input.

Comment: @konforce: At last all we have to use the code in production they why we suggest eval

Comment: @Fela, you should _always_ be validating the user input whether you use `eval` or not. If you are validating that `$a` and `$b` are proper numbers and that `$char` is a proper operation then `eval` will be safe. That said, I would still not use `eval` on a public site.

Comment: if it's a local project, there is no reason not to use `eval`.

Comment: I'm not using eval, I'm using switches with different operators. All user input is sanitised of course.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to avoid creating a switch/case, could be:

```
<?php 
// Doesn't matter if $a and $b are integers or strings
$a = 100;
$b = 1000;
$operator = ">";

$operations = [
  '='  => $a == $b,
  '>'  => $a > $b,
  '>=' => $a >= $b,
  '<'  => $a < $b,
  '<=' => $a <= $b,
  '<>' => $a <> $b,
];

// It will get the value of $a > $b and the result will be false
$operations[$operator]
?>
```

Finally if you prefer, you can move the $operations array, to a function to improve the readability code.

```
<?php 
// Doesn't matter if $a and $b are integers or strings
$a = 100;
$b = 1000;
$operator = ">";

// It will get the value of $a > $b and the result will be false
$result = getOperationResult($a, $b, $operator);

function getOperationResult(string|int $a, string|int $b, string $operator): bool
{
    $operations = [
      '='  => $a == $b,
      '>'  => $a > $b,
      '>=' => $a >= $b,
      '<'  => $a < $b,
      '<=' => $a <= $b,
      '<>' => $a <> $b,
    ];

    return $operations[$operator];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function. you will need to build a proper php command and run inside the eval() to extract out the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `eval` however I would not suggest using `eval`.

If there is case operator can by anything  you should check what operator is before using

```
switch($char)
{
  case '*':
    $result= $a * $b;
    break;

  case '+':
    $result= $a + $b;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm going to go with that option. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$a = 'alex';
$b = "alex";
$c = "==";
function abc($a,$b,$c){
  $d = 'return ($a '.$c.' $b) ? true : false;';
  return eval($d);
}
if(abc($a,$b,$c)){
  echo "condition true";
}else{
  echo "condition false";
}
// echo $e;
?>
```

Comment: please explain your solution