# Php : how to evaluate string to operator?

Tags: php, operators

I have 3 variables :

```
$a = 5;
$b = 3
$o = "*";
```

The $o variable contains a string value. This value can also be "/", "+", "-".

So when I concatenate $a.$o.$b :

```
$result = $a.$o.$b;

echo $result;
```

The result is `5*3` (a string) instead of `15`.

So how to convert operator string into real operator ?

Comment: `switch($o) {case '+': $result = $a + $b; break; case '-': $result = $a - $b; break; case '*': $result = $a * $b; break; case '/': $result = $a / $b; break; }`

Comment: Hi Mark Baker, thank you for phpexcel, I use it !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP use string as operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780478/php-use-string-as-operator)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you'd need to make a function or a switch statement to check each of the operators.

[Read this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780478/php-use-string-as-operator) so you'll understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, short and save solution:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 3
$o = "*";

$simplecalc = function($a,$b,$op) {
 switch($op):
  case "*":
  return $a*$b;
 case "+":
  return $a+$b;
 case "-":
  return $a-$b;
 case "/";
  return $a/$b;
 default:
  return false;
 endswitch;
};

$result = $simplecalc($a,$b,$o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it, by using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). But it hurts to recommend using eval, so I just give you a link to another question with a good answer: [calculate math expression from a string using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)

Comment: Thank you, I think I can use eval securely because the three variables don't come from user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval. For example:

```
eval('echo 5*3;')
```

will echo the number 15.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
$a = 5;
$b = 3;
$o = "*";
$result =  eval( "echo $a$o$b;" );  
echo $result;
```

Please note that using eval() is very dangerous, because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code.

Comment: $result = eval("return ".$a.$o.$b.";");