# can we convert a string into a sign in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a calculator in PHP now I have written a function in php to add few numbers but its concatenate instead of adding it can someone please help me guide me to do the task.

```
function cal($val1 , $opt , $val2){
  return $sum =  $val1 . $opt . $val2;
}
```

Now, if I'm calling this function like:

```
echo cal(4,"+",5);
```

It returns `4+5`  but I'm looking `9` for an answer 
 can it be possible that $opt works as an operator instead of a string and i can add or subtract based on operators like

Comment: well, `.` IS the concatenation operator... so how should it do anything *but* concatenate?

Comment: You should use `eval()`

Comment: @Mohammad you should *never* use `eval()` unless there is absolutely no other way. in this case, there is. looking at what the operator is and implementing the function.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann No, it is safe if you checked parameter,

Comment: @Mohammad concidering the question, i'm pretty sure the parameters aren't checked.

Comment: @Mohammad The issue with statements like "it is safe if you checked parameter" is that you have to be absolutely certainly that you think of all possible things that might occur. Is that _really_ realistic? I agree that `eval()` typically is to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: its just a prototype its working fine i ve completed it with switch but i wanted to concise it make it more dynamic we can make a string int or float or any other thing why not making it an operator ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP use string as operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780478/php-use-string-as-operator)

Comment: @mohammad eval() is one good way of doing thanks for suggestion is it   any other day

Comment: Check answer of @Zaid Yasyaf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129102/can-we-convert-a-string-into-a-sign-in-php#40129229

Comment: Mark an answer as correct since there are solutions to you question so other people don't have to make the same question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do an if statement or a switch case one;

example

```
if ($opt =='+'){
   return $val1+$val2;
}else if($opt =='-'){ 
   return $val1-$val2;
} .... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) run string as code. You should check values before using it.

```
function cal($val1 , $opt , $val2){
    if (is_numeric($val1, $val2) && preg_match("/[+-\/\*%]/", $opt))
        return eval($val1 . $opt . $val2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well yo can use a very basic approach for your program
like

```
switch ($opt) {
    case "+":
    echo  $val1 + $val2;
    break;
   case "-":
    echo  $val1 - $val2;;
    break;
   case "*":
    echo  $val1 * $val2;;
    break;
    ...
   default:
    code to be executed if $opt is different from all labels;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval` for this purpose, but validate your data carefully. As this advise in manual states:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

```
function cal($val1 , $opt , $val2)
{
    if (!is_numeric($val1)) return false;
    if (!is_numeric($val2)) return false;
    if (!in_array($opt, ["+", "-", "*", "/"])) return false;

    return eval("return $val1 $opt $val2;");
}

echo cal(3.2, "*", 4.2);
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ab10740e1e6cb9ed5e8abfe3b13ab29c621a4fa)